# Select value from column and make it act like a field

Tags: sql-server

i'm doing a chart, i need to select

```
SELECT Bid
 , ID
 , date
 , CASE
     WHEN status IS NULL THEN 'unsuccessful'
     WHEN status = 'Won' THEN 'successful'
WHERE  status = 'Won'
    OR status IS NULL
```

But i want that the value from the status example unsucessful is display as field

Comment: What are the columns that you want in the output result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes according to requirements in comments.**

As I understand, you need your query to give you four columns: Year, Month, NumberOfWins, NumberOfFails.

Thus grouping by Year and Month is necessary. For each Year and Month combination you need to know number of rows that have `status IS NULL` condition true, and number of rows, that have `status = 'Won'` condition true.

Please verify if this query suits your needs:

```
SELECT
 YEAR(date) as Year,
 MONTH(date) as Month,
 SUM(case when status IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) as NumberOfFails,
 SUM(case when status = 'Won' then 1 else 0 end) as NumberOfWins
FROM
 <your-table-name-here>
WHERE status = 'Won'
    OR status IS NULL
GROUP BY
 YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
ORDER BY
 Year, Month
```

Notice, that `WHERE` condition is only necessary if you have plenty of rows that do not match neither condition (I am not sure whether SQL Server would be able to optimize it).

I've also added `ORDER BY` clause as you probably would like to order data in your chart.

I've also assumed, that by writing 'month' you actually meant year and month. If that is not true simply remove year related statements from the query.

Comment: if i want the each result either for successful and unsuccessful to act like a field

Comment: This question I don't understand. Please extend your original question and provide more information on what you want to achieve.

Comment: you know i want to create a chart, in the chart i want to show, the number of successful bid and unsuccessful per month, so i need to represent successful and successful as a field.

Comment: Please check if changed answer suits your needs.